# Audited table and foreign key

Tags: sql, foreign-keys, azure-sql-database, audit

I have a database with multiples tables that must be audited.

As an example, I have a table of objects defined with an unique ID, a name and a description.

The name will always be the same. It is not possible to update it. "ObjectA" will always be "ObjectA".

As you see the name is not unique in the database but only in the logic.

The rows "from", "to" and "creator_id" are used to audit the changes. "from" is the date of the change, "to" is the date when a new row has been added and is null when it is the latest row. "creator_id" is the ID of the user that made the change.

```
+----+----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
| id |   name   | description  |         from         |          to          | creator_id |
+----+----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
|  1 | ObjectA  | My object    | 2021-05-30T00:05:00Z | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z |         18 |
|  2 | ObjectB  | My desc      | 2021-05-30T02:07:25Z | null                 |         15 |
|  3 | ObjectA  | Super object | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z | null                 |         20 |
+----+----------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

Now I have another table that must have a foreign key to this object table based on the "unique" object name.

```
+----+---------+-------------+
| id |   foo   | object_name |
+----+---------+-------------+
|  1 | blabla  | ObjectA     |
|  2 | wawawa  | ObjectB     |
+----+---------+-------------+
```

How can I create this link between those 2 tables ?

I already tried to create another table with a uuid and add a column "unique_identifier" in the object table. The foreign key will be then linked to this uuid table and not the object table. The issue is that I have multiple tables with this problem and I will have to create the double number of table.

It is also possible to use the object ID as the FK instead of the name but it would mean that I must update every table with that FK with the new ID when updating an object.

Comment: You don't clearly say what you are trying to accomplish. Explain what "create this link between those 2 tables" means. You don't say what the restriction on valid DB states is. You say "the foreign key" but it's not clear what FK you mean or why you don't just declare that FK & it seems you may not even be talking about a FK but are saying "FK" when you mean something else that just reminds you of a FK. [mre] [ask] [Help] PS "in the logic" is not clear. PS A subrow that allows NULL is unlikely to be appropriate as a unique identifier in SQL & in particular such a subrow can't match a FK.

Answer (score 0):

By the SQL standard, a foreign key must reference either the primary key or a unique key of the parent table. If the primary key has multiple columns, the foreign key must have the same number and order of columns. Therefore the foreign key references a unique row in the parent table; there can be no duplicates.

Another solution is to use trigger, you can check the existence of the object in objects table before you insert into another table.

**Update : Adding code**

Prepare the tables and create trigger: (I have only included 3 columns in Objects table for simplicity. In trigger, I am just printing the error in else part, you could raise error suing RAISEERROR function to return the error to client)

```
  Create table AuditObjects(id int identity (1,1),ObjectName varchar(20), ObjectDescription varchar(100) )
    Insert into AuditObjects values('ObjectA','description ObjectA Test')
    Insert into AuditObjects values('ObjectB','description ObjectB Test')
    Insert into AuditObjects values('ObjectC','description ObjectC Test')
    Insert into AuditObjects values('ObjectB','description ObjectB Test')
    Insert into AuditObjects values('ObjectB','description ObjectB Test')
    Insert into AuditObjects values('ObjectA','description ObjectA Test')
    
    Create table ObjectTab2 (id int identity (1,1),foo varchar(200), ObjectName varchar(20))
    go
    
    CREATE TRIGGER t_CheckObject ON ObjectTab2 INSTEAD OF INSERT
    AS BEGIN
        
        Declare @errormsg varchar(200), @ObjectName varchar(20)
        select @ObjectName = objectname from INSERTED
        if exists(select 1 from AuditObjects where objectname = @ObjectName)
        Begin
            INSERT INTO ObjectTab2 (foo, Objectname)
            Select foo, Objectname
            from INSERTED
        End
        Else
        Begin
            Select @errormsg = 'Object '+objectname+ ' does not exists in AuditObjects table'
            from Inserted
    
            print(@errormsg)
        End
        
    END;
```

Now if you try to insert a row in ObjectTab2 with object name as "ObjectC", insert will be allowed as "objectC" is present in audit table.

```
Insert into ObjectTab2 values('blabla', 'ObjectC')
Select * from ObjectTab2

id          foo    ObjectName
----------- ------ --------------------
1           blabla ObjectC
```

However, if you try to enter "ObjectD", it will not make an insert and give error msg in output.

```
Insert into ObjectTab2 values('Inserting ObjectD', 'ObjectD')
Object ObjectD does not exists in AuditObjects table
```

Well its not what you asked for but give you the same functionality and results.

Comment: Then I would have "name" and "to" has primary key for example ? But then i would have to have 2 columns in my second table "object_name" and "object_to" ? right ?

Comment: @Weedoze , I Added code to my previous post.

Answer (score 0):

Can you not still go ahead with linking the two tables based on 'object name'. The only difference would be - when you join the two tables, you would get multiple records from table1 (the first table you were referencing). You may then add filter condition based on from and to, as per your requirements.

Post Edit -
What I meant is, you can still achieve the desired results without introducing Foreign Key in this scenario -

Let's call your tables - Table1 and Table2

```
--Below will give you all records from Table1
SELECT T2.*, T1.description, T1.creator_id, T1.from, T1.to 
FROM TABLE2 T2 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T2.OBJECT_NAME = T1.NAME;

--Below will give you ONLY those records from Table1 whose TO is null
SELECT T2.*, T1.description, T1.creator_id, T1.from, T1.to 
FROM TABLE2 T2 
INNER JOIN TABLE1 T1 ON T2.OBJECT_NAME = T1.NAME
WHERE T1.TO IS NULL;
```

Comment: No because a foreign key must reference either a primary key or a unique key which is not the case

Comment: I have updated my answer, assuming you can still do away without Foreign Key

Answer (score 0):

I decided to go with an additional table to have this final design:

> Table "Object"

```
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
| id PK |            identifier FK             |  name   | description  |         from         |          to          | creator_id |
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
|     1 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | ObjectA | My object    | 2021-05-30T00:05:00Z | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z |         18 |
|     2 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-524887451057 | ObjectB | My desc      | 2021-05-30T02:07:25Z | null                 |         15 |
|     3 | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 | ObjectA | Super object | 2021-05-31T05:04:36Z | null                 |         20 |
+-------+--------------------------------------+---------+--------------+----------------------+----------------------+------------+
```

> Table "Object_identifier"

```
+--------------------------------------+
|              identifier PK           |
+--------------------------------------+
| 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 |
| 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-524887451057 |
+--------------------------------------+
```

> Table "foo"

```
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------+
| id PK |  foo   |         object_identifier FK         |
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------+
|     1 | blabla | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-426614174000 |
|     2 | wawawa | 123e4567-e89b-12d3-a456-524887451057 |
+-------+--------+--------------------------------------+
```